# How to get currentSrc of img tag in javscript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to get src of img tag from QR-code. But showing blank in console log with script below

```js
$('#qrcode > img').each(function() {
  console.log($(this));
  [currentSrc][1]
  console.log($(this)[0].currentSrc);
  //return blank value in console "empty" 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode" title="A491">
  <canvas width="400" height="400" style="display: none;"></canvas>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `[currentSrc][1]` statement. Don't know what's the purpose of the same here. Try again after that.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/mnxtjp98/) (w/o the reference error) -> Add a [mcve]

Comment: why jquery `this` if you are wanting to use the html element object?